# How to filter data from SQL concatenating two columns in c#?

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

Is there a way to do `.Where(c. => c.filters.Name)` but also check for surname?

**SO:** Given this input filter `"John Doe"` where `John` is the name and `Doe` is the surname.
And given that i have two column in the database one for `name` and one for `surname` how can i filter correclty:

**For example**:

- if user inputs "John" i'll filter for all the John in the database (including John Doe)
- AND if user inputs "Doe" i'll filter for all the Doe in the database (including John Doe)
- if user inputs "John Doe" i'll filter for all the John Doe in the database (can't get this one to work)

I tried this:

```cs
query.Where(x => x.Name.Contains(filters.Name.Trim()) || x.Surname == filters.Name.Trim());
```

But that does not filter when the input is "John Doe"... any idea on how to do this?

Comment: What should happen for a "Doe John" input? For me it sounds like you want/need a calculated field containing Name and Surname and put a fulltext index on that column. Don't know how that's surfaced in EF.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

should be as simple as

```
query.Where(x => (x.Name + " " + x.Surname).ToLower().Contains(filters.Name.Trim()));
```

Comment: Is not that simple, thanks for the reply but i decided to split the two inputs in frontend. So i can filter name and surname separately.

Comment: @devludo it worked for me. ef generated `WHERE LOWER([Extent1].[Name] + N' ' + [Extent1].[Surname]) LIKE N'%John Doe%'`. Which error did you get?

Answer (score 0):

Add the property **FullName** your model.

```
[NotMapped]
public string FullName => $"{Name} {LastName}"
```

Then you can search using

```
string pattern = $@"(\w*{search.ToLower().Trim()}\w*)";
query.Where(x => Regex.IsMatch(x.FullName.ToLower(), pattern));
```

You will need to add

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions
```